# Getting different Facebook Mutual Friend on Simulator and Device

Tags: ios, iphone, facebook, ipad, facebook-graph-api

I am using Facebook api to get Mutual Friend, but with the same account I am getting different number of Mutual Friend on Simulator and on actual devices.
The code I am using :

```
NSDictionary *params = @{
                         @"fields": @"context.fields(all_mutual_friends.fields(picture.width(200).height(200),id,name)),id,name"
                         };

FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",facebookId]
                              parameters:params
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                      id result,
                                      NSError *error) {
    // Handle the result
    if (error) {            
        NSLog(@"%@", error);            

    } else {
        NSLog(@"%@", result);

        NSArray *fbResData = [app checkArrayNull:[[[result objectForKey:@"context"] objectForKey:@"all_mutual_friends"] objectForKey:@"data"]];

        NSLog(@"%@", fbResData);                                              
    }
}];
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer after some R&D from google.
Just need to add Access Tocken in FBSDKGraphRequest at every call.

```
 FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                              initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@",facebookId]
                              parameters:params
                              tokenString:strAccessTocken
                              version:nil
                              HTTPMethod:@"GET"];
```

And got the Mutual Friends on every call.